# Manipulating matrix data member in a Struct pointer method

Tags: pointers, matrix, struct, go

I am working on creating a struct that represents a Matrix with methods to manipulate the data within the type. There are two methods that I use as an example to set a single row or column to a specific value. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
type Matrix struct {
    Height, Width int
    data [][]int
}

func NewMatrix(nrows, ncols int) (mat *Matrix) {
    mat = new(Matrix)
    mat.Height = nrows
    mat.Width = ncols
    mat.data = make([][]int, nrows)
    for i := range mat.data {
        mat.data[i] = make([]int, ncols)
        for j := range mat.data[i]{
            mat.data[i][j] = 0
        }
    }
    return
}

func (mat *Matrix) SetCol(col, val int) {
    for i := 0; i < mat.Height; i++ {
        mat.data[i][col] = val
    }
}


func (mat *Matrix) SetRow(row, val int) {
    for i := 0; i < mat.Width; i++ {
        mat.data[row][i] = val
    }
}
```

When I use this `Matrix` type and manipulating the `data` attribute like so:

```
mat := NewMatrix(33,33)
mat.SetCol(2, 3)
mat.SetRow(2, 3)
```

I am finding that the `data` attribute of the `Matrix` instance is being set within the method `SetCol` but once it returns from this method the `data` appears to be the empty matrix that I initialized it to.

Why is the `data` attribute that I am manipulating in the method not persisting past the lifetime of the method call? How can I fix this?

Edit

I found out that the issue was that I was instantiating a new instance of a `Matrix` on each iteration in a loop which is why the matrix always appeared to be empty after I manipulated it with `SetCol` and `SetRow`. So the question is not really valid.

Comment: http://play.golang.org/p/Ry1L2D0KCC it works fine, how are you checking the value? btw you don't need the loop to set it to 0, it's 0 by default.

Comment: Thanks very much @OneOfOne. I didn't realize that I didn't need to initialize the the values to 0. I was checking my values by summing the values of the rows. I found out the issue though and it turned out to be a pretty stupid error. The commands that I was executing on the matrix were in a loop and I was instantiating a new instance of the matrix within the loop so I was clearing the matrix on each iteration, hence the reason that I never saw that the matrix was always empty.

Comment: Happens to everyone :) Good lucking with Go!